# Implement Redis Cache in place of In Memory Cache?

Tags: asynchronous, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

I have a InMemory Cache method which I want to implement using Redis Cache, it uses the concept of Semaphore in the InMemory Cache, hence I have gone through many documentation's like the Redis documentation on [Distributed Locking](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-2-distributed-locking/), and tried using different locking mechanisms in Redis such as [RedLock.Net](https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net) , [RedLock-cs](https://github.com/kidfashion/redlock-cs) etc, but I haven't been able to completely go through with the technique, as even though I am able to recreate the method, but the running time for large number of processes for it in Redis is coming out to be huge.

The code that I am trying to recreate is as follows:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<SemaphoreSlim>> _semaphores = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<SemaphoreSlim>>();

public async ValueTask<TValue> GetMethod<TValue>(string key,Func<Task<TValue>> get,int time)
{
    return await SemaphoreMethod(key, async() => 
    {
        var value = await get();
        if(value != null)
            cache.set(key,value,time);
        return value;
     });
}

private async ValueTask<TValue> SemaphoreMethod<TValue>(string key,Func<Task<TValue>> get)
{
    if(cache.TryGetValue(key,out TValue result))
        return result;
    var semaphore = _semaphores.GetOrAdd(key,k => new Lazy<SemaphoreSlim>(() => new SemaphoreSlim(1,1))).Value;
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    TValue answer = default;
    
    if(cache.TryGetValue(key,out TValue result2))
        return result2;
    answer = await get();

    _semaphores.TryRemove(key,out _);
    semaphore.Release();

    return answer;
}
```

And the method which I run against it to check it's implementation and efficiency in comparison to InMemory Cache is  as follows:

```
public async Task GetValueAsync_Tasks()
{
    var callCount = 0;
    
    async Task<string> Get()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref callCount);
        return "value";
    }

    const int count = 1000;
    var valueTasks = new List<ValueTask<string>>(count);
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
        valueTask.Add(GetMethod("key",Get));
    
    var tasks = valueTasks.Select(vt => vt.AsTask()).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    callCount.Should().Be(1);
}
```

One other thing that I am not able to understand that in which part of the test method, would the code run all the tasks created, i.e. in this one
`valueTasks.Add(sut.GetValueAsync("key", FetchValue));`
or in this one
`Task.WaitAll(tasks);`

I am using the StackExchange.Redis library, and Azure Cache for Redis for storing the respective data.